# Method calling in java using multi threading

Tags: java, multithreading

While writing a program using `multi threading` we had a method containing `run` method in different threads. They used `thread.start` instead of `thread.run`. Could someone explain what's the reason behind not calling the method by its name?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question but I would suggest you to manage threads with `Executors`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html

Comment: This seems to be answered here, have a look: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/java-whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/java-whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run)

Answer (score 0):

The method Thread.run() would execute the method in the current or main thread.
Whereas the method Thread.start() would execute the logic in a separate thread.

More Information
[What's the difference between Thread start() and Runnable run()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/java-whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run)

Answer (score 0):

If you call the run() method directly on your class, it will execute the code in the main thread. When you use the Thread.start() method a new thread is created. The JVM then calls your run() method when the thread is allowed to run.

Have a look at the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.start() creates a new thread and calls runnable parallelly where as Thread.run() works as just a method call.i.e, no thread is created,So we mostly use Thread.start()

Answer (score 0):

1. `Thread.start` **will create a new thread** from the current running code and **call** `Thread.run` function.
2. `Thread.run` will call this class's `run` method without creating a new thread.

Thread.java:

```
public synchronized void start() {
    /**
     * This method is not invoked for the main method thread or "system"
     * group threads created/set up by the VM. Any new functionality added
     * to this method in the future may have to also be added to the VM.
     *
     * A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW".
     */
    if (threadStatus != 0 || this != me)
        throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
    group.add(this);
    start0();
    if (stopBeforeStart) {
        stop0(throwableFromStop);
    }
}
public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

JDK `Thread` class: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk6/jdk6/jdk/file/5672a2be515a/src/share/classes/java/lang/Thread.java