# Below code runs successfully, so does it mean we can start thread twice?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-exceptions

Below code runs successfully, so does it mean we can start thread twice?

```
public class enu extends Thread {
    static int count = 0;

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("running count "+count++);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        enu obj = new enu();
        obj.run();
        obj.start();
    }
}
```

output - 
running count 0
running count 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you only started a new thread once, when you called `obj.start()`. `obj.run()` executes the `run` method in the current thread. It doesn't create a new thread, and you can call it as many times as you like.

On the other hand, calling `obj.start()` more than once is not possible.

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/java-whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run) has some more details on the differences.

Comment: When start() method is called on a thread, it itself calls the run() method automatically.

Answer (score 0):

The Thread lifecycle ends at Thread.State.TERMINATED.

All you did was running the `run()` method from the same thread - the `main`-Thread.

Theres a really simple test if you want to check the access of Threads in code parts:

```
public class randtom extends Thread {
static int count = 0;

public void run(){
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().toString());      
    System.out.println("running count "+count++);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    randtom obj = new randtom();
    obj.run();
    obj.start();
}}
```

Running this results in:

```
Thread[main,5,main]
running count 0
Thread[Thread-0,5,main]
running count 1
```

Hope this clarifies!