# Why is Thread.sleep not working

Tags: android

I am new to android and Java and I am having trouble using the Thread.sleep function.My program is a simple game that's almost like table tennis with two players. The code is not complete but the Thread is not working properly.I am changing the margins to move the ball.Is the catch block being run because of some exception > My code is as follows :

```
package com.example.game;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private int x1=0,x2=0,m=150;
public int height;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
      Point size= new Point();
      display.getSize(size);
//        int width = size.x;
      height = size.y;
      showview2();
      showview1();
      game();
}
public void game()
{
    buttonSetup1_rig();
    buttonSetup1_lef();
    buttonSetup2_rig();
    buttonSetup2_lef();

//while(m>=0)
    for(int i=0;i<150;i++)
    {
        showball();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {

                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    m=m-10; 

                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }).start();
    }
   }

    protected void buttonSetup1_rig()
    {
      ImageButton ticon=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
      ticon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if(x1<(height-320))
              x1=x1+10;
              showview1();
        }
});
    }
    protected void buttonSetup1_lef()
    {
      ImageButton ticon=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
      ticon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if(x1>(0))
              x1=x1-10;
              showview1();
        }
});
    }
    protected void buttonSetup2_rig()
    {
      ImageButton ticon=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
      ticon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if(x2<(height-320))
              x2=x2+10;
              showview2();
        }
});
    }
    protected void buttonSetup2_lef()
    {
      ImageButton ticon=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
      ticon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              if(x2>(0))
              x2=x2-10;
              showview2();
        }
});
    }

   public void showview1()
     {
          ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp ;
          lp=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)(image.getLayoutParams());
          lp.setMargins(x1,0,0,0);
          image.setLayoutParams(lp);
     }
   public void showview2()
     {
          ImageView image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
          LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp ;
          lp=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)(image.getLayoutParams());
          lp.setMargins(x2,0,0,0);
          image.setLayoutParams(lp);
     }
   public void showball()
    {
        ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams l ;
        l=(LinearLayout.LayoutParams)(img.getLayoutParams());
        int leftMargin = l.leftMargin;
        int rightMargin = l.rightMargin;
        int topMargin = l.topMargin;
        l.setMargins(m,0,m,0);
        img.setLayoutParams(l);
    }
```

}

My Xml is :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/left" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/right" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/lc" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="120dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
                android:src="@drawable/untitled" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
                android:src="@drawable/lc" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:layout_weight="2.25" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/left" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post the exception also.

Comment: I dont know if there is an exception.I am just guessing

Comment: Your question is quite vague, but maybe this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8579695/1535436

Comment: Are you aware that you are starting 150 threads that are running at the same time?

Comment: Will there be 150 threads running at the same time or will there be one thread running 150 times? I am sorry if my question is dumb but i am very new to Android.

Comment: @Sourav There will be 150 new threads running asynchronously. Main thread will continue to run and those threads that you create will be sleeping in background.

Comment: So should I use my loop inside the try block so that only one thread is running but it sleeps for 5 secs after decrementing m by 10?