# Java multi-client socket server - starvation

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Consider the following Server:

```
public class TestServer {


public static void main(String[] args) {


    String ksName = "/some/path/keystore-server.jks";
    char ksPass[] = "password".toCharArray();
    char ctPass[] = "pswd".toCharArray();

    KeyStore ks;
    try {
        ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
        ks.load(new FileInputStream(ksName), ksPass);
        KeyManagerFactory kmf = 
        KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
        kmf.init(ks, ctPass);
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
        SSLServerSocketFactory ssf = sc.getServerSocketFactory();
        SSLServerSocket s   = (SSLServerSocket) ssf.createServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);                

        while(true){                
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) s.accept();
            System.out.println("New Client accepted");
            TestThread t = new TestThread(sslsocket);
            t.run();      
        }

    } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | CertificateException | UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyManagementException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TotalControlServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
}
```

}

The above is a simple server that accepts several clients: right after accepting a new connection, a dispatch a new thread (TestThread) in order to deal with the client incoming requests. Here's the code for TestThread:

```
public class TestThread implements Runnable {

SSLSocket sslsocket;

public TestThread(SSLSocket sslsocket) {
    this.sslsocket = sslsocket;
}

@Override
public void run() {

    ObjectInputStream is = null;
    ObjectOutputStream os = null;
    try {
        is = new ObjectInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());
        os = new ObjectOutputStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());

        while(true){
            String p = (String) is.readObject();
            System.out.println("We got: " + p);

            os.writeObject(p.concat(p));
            os.flush();

        }//while         

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CmdLineService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CmdLineService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
            os.close();
            this.sslsocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CmdLineService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}//run
```

}

Simple enough, it just loops indefinitely reading Strings and sending back its concatenation with itself.

The client is also rather simple:

```
public class TestClient {


  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore" , "/path/keystore-client.jks")  ;
    ObjectOutputStream os = null;
    ObjectInputStream is = null;
    SSLSocket sslsocket = null;

    try {
        SSLSocketFactory f = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
        sslsocket = (SSLSocket) f.createSocket("localhost", SERVER_PORT);

        sslsocket.startHandshake();
        System.out.println("Authentication done");

        os = new ObjectOutputStream(sslsocket.getOutputStream());  
        is = new ObjectInputStream(sslsocket.getInputStream());


        BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        boolean exit = false;
        while(!exit){
            System.out.print("> ");
            String line = b.readLine();
            os.writeObject(line);
            os.flush();

            String s = (String) is.readObject();
            System.out.println(s);

        }//while

    } //main
    catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TotalControlCmdClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(TestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } finally {

        try {
            is.close();  
            sslsocket.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestClient.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }       
}
```

Just loops indefinitely sending strings and reading a string.

This works fine for one client.. However, if I start another client, it does not connect! It seems that I'm facing some kind of thread starvation issue..

How can I fix that?

Comment: Not calling 't.run();' would help a lot.  Think about what that does...

Comment: If you're still stuck, then :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/java-whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple: You never start a second listener Thread:

```
   while(true){                
            SSLSocket sslsocket = (SSLSocket) s.accept();
            System.out.println("New Client accepted");
            TestThread t = new TestThread(sslsocket);
            t.run();      
        }
```

Calling `run()` does not start the Thread, that is done using `start()`.
Therefore the main thread is processing the content of the `run()` method and as it is busy you can not connect using a second client.

Change `t.run()` to `t.start` and everything will be fine.

Comment: I'm surprised that the OP did not twig on to this when his/her debugger showed that execution never returned to the accept().

Comment: Yeah, after adding 'Thread T = new Thread(t); T.start()', it worked as expected.