# confusion while creating a thread by extending thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

we knew that we can create a new thread by creating a new class thats extends thread and then to create an instance of that thread..while going through this topic i saw an example in my book which is as follows.

```
 class NewThread extends Thread{
    NewThread(){
        super("demo thread");
        System.out.println("child thread:"+this);
        start();
    }
    public void run(){
        try{
            for(int i=5;i>0;i--){
                System.out.println("child thread"+i);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
         } catch(InterruptedException e){
             System.out.println("child interrupted");
         }
         System.out.println("exiting child thread");
      }
  }
```

in this example i am able to understand all those things except the constructor part in which we are not using any instance(thread) to call start().so my question is how the start() method is called without any thread.

Comment: If you do not understand why the `start()` call in your constructor does not need an explicit object reference, then you probably could make better use of your time by learning more about the Java language before you try to understand Java threads.

Answer (score 1):

You are inheriting the start() method from the class Thread that your NewThread class extends. So you can call it like any other method.

Same goes for the run() method which could use the @Override annotation in order to make the concept of inheritance clearer.

```
@Override
public void run() {
        try{
            for(int i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
                System.out.println("child thread" + i);
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
           System.out.println("child interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("exiting child thread");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is valid because method `start()` is inherited from `Thread` class, so you can call it like any other class method.

Answer (score 0):

This start() method is called on the thread instance, which has just been created in this constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Below code is responsible for calling `start()` method on your `NewThread` instance in `NewThread` constructor, which calls `start()` method in `Thread` class, which  calls `run()` method.

```
 NewThread(){
    super("demo thread");
    System.out.println("child thread:"+this);
    start();
}
```

Flow:

```
NewThread() -> start() -> Thread start() -> native start0() ->  run()
```

Refer to this SE question for internals of `Thread` class `start()` method :

[What's the difference between Thread start() and Runnable run()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/java-whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run/35931153#35931153)