# Is there a advantage of running a runnable in Main thread queue.I came across this piece of code in a open source

Tags: java, android

I can see this always executing on the main thread.

Code sample :

```
private interface Task {
    void run() throws ListenerException;
}

private void runUITask(final Task task) {
    (new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            task.run();
        }
    }).run();
}
```

Thank you in advance !!

Comment: There have to be clear shaped question and description. Please edit it in order to match the criteria.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between Thread start() and Runnable run()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run)

Comment: I don't think there is any queuing or threading in code shown... it looks like it will simply run the code as soon as `runUITask` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Runnable could be used along with handler when you want to give a certain amount of delay in execution of you piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Creating runnable creates a separate object with runs along with the main thread but you cannot update the UI using the runnable thread.
The one advantage is you can update using a handler for the runnable.
A Handler allows communicating back with UI thread from other background thread.Check this link for the differences.

http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/how-to-run-runnable-thread-or-ui-thread.html

Comment: new Runnable() doesnot create a new thread but lets you run the task inside it..but as far I know you cannot update the main thread using runnable.

Comment: Only when you create a new thread and runnble inside it,it will create a seperate thread..correct me if I am wrong...

Comment: Oh sorry thats a mistake..misleading