# Android skipping slideshow frames

Tags: android

I am trying to make a simple android app that will display some images for a user specifiable number of milliseconds each.
The code below skips to the last image after 11 seconds.
could you have a look and tell me what you think.

```
public void buttonPressed(View view){
        ImageView canvas = findViewById(R.id.canvas);
            delay(1000);
            canvas.setImageResource(R.drawable.c1);
        delay(1000);
            canvas.setImageResource(R.drawable.c2);
        delay(1000);
            canvas.setImageResource(R.drawable.c3);
        delay(1000);
            canvas.setImageResource(R.drawable.c4);
        delay(1000);
            canvas.setImageResource(R.drawable.c5);
        delay(5000);
            canvas.setImageResource(R.drawable.c6);
        delay(2000);
}
    void delay(long ms){
        long init = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        while(SystemClock.uptimeMillis() != init+ms);
    }
```

I am open to C/C++ alternatives.
I was wishing there was a 'call kernel' function for the display.
In the future I would like to have the user be able to select or take the pictures.

I am using a different approach:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private ImageView canvas;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            canvas = findViewById(R.id.canvas);
        }


        public void buttonPressed(View view){

            new STask().execute("start");

        }
        public class STask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
                long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                if(SystemClock.uptimeMillis() == start + 1000){
                    canvas.setImageResource(R.drawable.c2);
                    canvas.invalidate();
                }else if(SystemClock.uptimeMillis() == start + 3000){
                    canvas.setImageResource(R.drawable.c3);
                    canvas.invalidate();
                }else if(SystemClock.uptimeMillis() == start + 4500){
                    canvas.setImageResource(R.drawable.c4);
                    canvas.invalidate();
                }else if(SystemClock.uptimeMillis() == start + 8000){
                    canvas.setImageResource(R.drawable.c5);
                    canvas.invalidate();
                }else if(SystemClock.uptimeMillis() == start + 10000){
                    canvas.setImageResource(R.drawable.c6);
                    canvas.invalidate();

                }
                return null;
            }


        }

    }
```

I need  the AsyncTask to continually run in the background.

Comment: Is it skipping frames or do some of the frames last too long?

Comment: It is skipping frames

Comment: Does it help if you swap `!=` for `<`?

Comment: Either way, you should probably rewrite it so that you [don't lock the UI thread](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html) for prolonged periods. And in turn, doing so will probably solve your issue.

Comment: I tried to fix it and i get this in the log:

Comment: I/Choreographer: Skipped 821 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Comment: Here is my new code:

Comment: That's because you should use `Thread.start` instead of `Thread.run`. See the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by putting the delays on a separate thread and making a Runnable to change the slide and running that on the UI thread.