# Java - Is this method multithreaded?

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, parallel-processing

First of all, thanks for taking time to read this. The code is written and executed as a JUnit test, so I dont know whether that affects the answer.

```
@Test
public void generate___() {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    for (File file : getResultsFromFolder("C:\\temp\\....")) {
        class runnableClass implements Runnable{
            public void run() {
                // do something with file

            }
        }
        new runnableClass().run();
    }

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("total took: " + (endTime - startTime) / 1000000); //divide by 1000000 to get milliseconds.
}
```

Comment: Depends if `getResultsFromFolder` is multithreaded.  Otherwise, I don't see the creation of any threads.

Comment: I don't agree with Jacob; Since you are creating and running a new thread (Runnable) for each file you get from `getResultsFromFolder("C:\\temp\\....")`, it is multithreaded

Comment: @ArnauldAlex A `Runnable` is not a `Thread`.

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.fr/2012/01/difference-thread-vs-runnable-interface.html 
Ok it's hard to see the difference but ok.

Comment: @ArnauldAlex, the article you linked has a misleading title.  It does not explain the difference between what a `Thread` _is_, and what a `Runnable` is.  A `Thread` is an object with a magic method `start()` that creates a new thread.  `Runnable` is just an interface:  It doesn't _do_ anything at all.  If you create a class that _implements_ runnable, then you will be allowed to store it in `Runnable` variables and pass it to functions that take a `Runnable` argument.  But the compiler will require your class to have a `run()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method is not multi threaded due to the creation of Runnable instance in your method.

***Example to showcase answer:***

***Code***

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            };
            myRunnable.run();
        }
    }
```

***Output***

```
main
main
main
main
main
main
main
main
main
main
```

To make this method multi threaded you could use an ExecutorService.

***Code***

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        };

        executorService.execute(myRunnable);
    }

    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

***Output***

```
pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-2
pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-2
pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-2
pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-2
pool-1-thread-1
pool-1-thread-2
```

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating this. Is there a quick tweak to change it to be multithreaded?

Comment: I've updated my answer to showcase the use of an ExecutorService to make this multi threaded. Please accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: Thanks! This exactly matches the implementation of some colleagues. ExecutorService.execute is the trick!

Comment: I am able to get this to multithread, but the code block in the run() method does not behave as expected. Any clues on where I can start to look?

Comment: Can you update your question with the code in the run method and I can try and help.

Comment: Thanks!! New question posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926689/java-multithreaded-method-not-behaving-as-expected

Answer (score 2):

No it is not.

```
new runnableClass().run();
```

This calls the `run` method directly as defined above it.

If you want this code to be multithreaded you will need to use:

```
new Thread(new runnableClass()).start();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the runnable will be executed by the main caller thread, just like this:

```
for (File file : getResultsFromFolder("C:\\temp\\....")) {
     // do something with file
}
```

To make it multi-threaded, you can create new threads and call `start()`:

```
for (final File file : getResultsFromFolder("C:\\temp\\....")) {
    class runnableClass implements Runnable{
        public void run() {
            // do something with file
        }
    }
    new Thread(new runnableClass()).start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer!

Comment: @AllenH. no problem :)

Comment: @AllenH. chech this for more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run

Comment: I am able to get this to multithread, but the code block in the run() method does not behave as expected. Any clues on where I can start to look?

Comment: @AllenH. Better to create a new question and post more details.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! New question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49926689/java-multithreaded-method-not-behaving-as-expected

Answer (score 1):

As a complement see this tutorial, it explains well what you want to know.
And it has example

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_multithreading.htm