# Using methods inside a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

When I try to use methods inside a class in which I extend `Thread` it does not receive the methods after the run.

My class:

```
public class PassPhraseValidator<E> extends Thread {

    private List<E> list;
    private boolean isValid;
    private String passPhrase;
    public PassPhraseValidator(List<E> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public String getPassPhrase() {
        return passPhrase;
    }

    public boolean isValid() {
        return isValid;
    }

    public void run(){
        this.passPhrase = Arrays.toString(list.toArray());
        this.isValid = list.stream().filter(e -> Collections.frequency(list, e) > 1).count() == 0;
    }
}
```

So when I execute this class like this:

```
PassPhraseValidator<Integer> validIntegerPassPhrase = new PassPhraseValidator<>(Arrays.asList(12, 18, 15, 32));
validIntegerPassPhrase.start();
System.out.println(validIntegerPassPhrase.getPassPhrase() + " valid: " + validIntegerPassPhrase.isValid());
```

It gives me false while it should be true because the run function wasn't ran yet.

What am I doing wrong here? How can I make multithreading part of this? It does work when I directly put it inside the methods.

Comment: The default for a boolean field is false! It starts with that value! Beyond that, there are potential visibility issue in multi threading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `System.out.println` statement does not wait for your thread (the `run` function) to complete.

One way to wait for its completion is to call the `join` method

```
validIntegerPassPhrase.join();  //Need to handle the InterruptedException it might throw
System.out.println(validIntegerPassPhrase.getPassPhrase() + " valid: " + validIntegerPassPhrase.isValid());
```

Comment: Thank you that works! I had a hunch it ran before the run() but I didn't know how to handle it.

Comment: Calling `run` will make it run on the main thread itself (which defeats the purpose of a Thread)

Comment: That confuses me a little. You mean I shouldn't do it this way? Should I just put `return Arrays.toString(list.toArray());` for example inside `getPassPhrase()`?

Comment: I meant if you do `validIntegerPassPhrase.run()`, then no new thread will be created. The `run` logic will run on the main thread itself. You can print the name of the thread by `Thread.currentThread().getName()`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

What you are doing is called *multithreading*. This allows multiple threads to execute code [concurrency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_(computer_science)) or in parallel. Programs run on something called the [main thread](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=298). This means one thread is executing all code systematically; one instruction after another. When introducing another thread like you are, the program execution is being done on different logic at the *same time*. So, when you execute the `start()` method on your implementation of the `thread` class, you are causing it to execute it's respective `run()` method in the background until; it completes, an exception is thrown, the application is shutdown, or the thread is stopped.

Lets step through your code and analyze the scenario.

1. Thread object is instantiated by the `main thread`. Lets call this new thread `thread2`.
2. `thread2` is started by the `main thread`.
3. `thread2` and the `main thread` are both running in parallel. This means code is being executed by both of them (for simplicity) at the *same time*.
4. Two possibilities could be occurring for this issue; [Java Memory Barrier](https://www.infoq.com/articles/memory_barriers_jvm_concurrency) (beyond the scope of this question but more reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model)) or timing. The `main thread` is most likely reading the print statement before `thread2` can finish it's respective `run()` method.

---

**Solution**

1. An approach may be not to use multi-threading at all. The creation of threads is quite a costly operation and should not be done frequently. Typically, in app's that require multi-threading [thread-pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) are utilized instead.
2. Utilize the `join()` blocking function. Join forces the calling thread (in this case it would be the `main thread`) to *wait* for the respective thread to finish execution before continuation.
3. Implement the thread with use of `Promise`. This object is a wrapper for the `Future` class, allowing for the `get()` method to be blocking. This means the calling thread (in this case it would be the `main thread`) to *wait* for the respective thread to finish execution before continuation. An example of `Promise`'s can be found [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/util/concurrent/java-8-concurrency-tutorial/).

Comment: Thank you this clarifies a lot. I have to use multithreading as it is the purpose of the exercise and my goal was to use this with multiple threads ofcourse. In my version this is implemented now and works like I want it!

Comment: Of course! I'm glad I was able to assist in your learning and understanding.