# I have a multi-threaded JAVA application running on a CPU with N cores(on Linux) however it only uses 0th core and rest of the cores are idle

Tags: java, linux, multithreading, parallel-processing, cpu-cores

If I am not wrong, JVM relies on underlying architecture of OS for scheduling and spreading threads to other cores (when a thread is spawned). However, in my application, I don't see it happening. Each and every thread is running on 0th core and rest N-1 cores are in idle states. Any specific reason why this is happening and, more over,  how to solve this issue so that I can utilize rest of my cores ?

I am aware of setting process affinity but that is, in a way, hardcoding a process to a specific core. Since a thread can be spawned at any given point, it should idly be processed by a core sitting idle.

Code Snippet e.g.

```
public static void main() {

R1 r1 = new R1();
R2 r2 = new R2();
Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);

t1.start();
t2.start();
}
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Hi! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) We can't help you with code we can't see. :-) Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem of using only a single core. (The most likely explanation -- all due respect! -- is that you're not starting the threads correctly.) Please also include details of your configuration (OS, etc.).

Comment: Hi, would be nice to see the code you are using. The following post could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run

Comment: Hard to answer without given code. Just a quick guess: Are you by chance using `Thread.run()` instead `Thread.start()`?

Comment: @Ametzaga,@MarkusBauer: it is Thread.start().

Comment: how do you see which core is busy and which are idle?

Comment: who told you java will run your threads on separate cores?

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov used `top` and `sysstat` commands.

Comment: @ACV Doesn't it? :)

Comment: the java language specification doesn't enforce it. Also remember a thread is not a process.

Comment: @AVC Yes I am aware of it. The essence of the problem is that thread should be running on separate core which is idle but it doesn't happen with my application.

Answer (score 1):

There is almost certainly something about your application that is causing the JVM not to be able to run more than one application thread at a time.

The problem will be in the `R1` and `R2` classes, or something that they depend on.  Since you have decided not to show them to us, we can only guess what it might be.  However a common explanation is that one of the threads (running your code) is holding a lock that the other thread is trying to acquire.  That can be sufficient to make your application *effectively* single threaded.

Advice:

- Use the `jstack` utility to get a thread dump of the application, and look at the stacktraces to see what the threads are doing, and why one is blocked.
- Run the application using a debugger, etcetera.
- Don't waste your time on investigating the scheduler, thread affinity or stuff like that.  They are unlikely to help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Most of them are asynchronous calls/threads running in parallel (not necessarily dependent on each other or on one specific resource). But even so, they are running on only one core. This baffles me. I am sure I am missing something at configuration level and it could be a silly mistake.

Regarding class structure, it is pretty much the same (I have written a blue print). 

I will try to debug again and will also explore `jstack` utility but is there any more possibility for such weird behavior ?

Kindly bump this question to get more views from others.

Comment: The most likely cause of your problems is your code.  Without seeing it (or an MCVE that reproduces the behavior), I can't speculate beyond what I have already said.  I don't think anyone else will be able to help you either.