# volatile keyword can't stop loop in java

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

```
public class VolatileOne {
    private static boolean ready ;
    private static int number ;

    private static class ReaderThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!ready){
                Thread.yield();
            }
            System.out.print(number);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReaderThread().run();
        ready = true;
        number = 50;
    }
}
```

After running this code, the program does not stop, which is obvious because the thread backs up variables ready into the memory of its own process. When I use volatile keyword to modify read

```
private volatile static boolean ready ;
```

the read variable will not be copied into process memory at this time. But the program can't stop. What's the reason? Is it related to the static keyword?

If you want the program to output 50 and return, what should you do?

Comment: Never call `run()` on a thread.

Comment: There are three problems in the code, so I do not think it's a duplicate.

Comment: @孙兴斌 - It can be a duplicate of multiple questions.

Comment: @MCEmperor, Calling `t.run()` may be an example of extremely poor _style_, and it may not do what the OP thinks it does, but it does _something,_ and that might be a thing that some programmer actually wants to do.  Instead of just saying, "Never call run()..." you might also say why not.

Comment: @ZheMa, Your program does not create any thread. A `Thread` object is not a thread. A `Thread` object is a _handle_ that your program can use to create and manage a thread, but the actual thread is not created until your program calls `.start()`. You normally never write any call to the `run()` method. Your `run()` method gets called _automatically_, inside the new thread, after the thread has been started.

Comment: @SolomonSlow I indeed could have better included a link to [the very first Google search result](https://beginnersbook.com/2015/03/why-dont-we-call-run-method-directly-why-call-start-method/) of my exact words, which reveals the why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need call `start` to execute the code in another thread. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8579702/6690200) for the difference between `run` and `start`.
2. Call `join` to wait the `ReaderThread` finish.
3. `volatile` keyword can build a [happens-before](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/memconsist.html) relationship between the write and the read thread, you can put `number = 50;` before `ready = true;`, which makes sure the reader will notice `number` is `50` when it notice `ready` is `true`.

Example:

```
Thread reader = new ReaderThread();
reader.start();
number = 50;
ready = true;
reader.join();
```