# Unexpected behavior while running the code and debugging

Tags: java, multithreading

while debugging result is 77777 otherwise 97777. 
Same behavior if we move **System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());** up and below while printing the co.code. 
any explanation?

```
public class Concepts extends Thread {
int code = 9;

public void run() {
    this.code = 7;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Concepts co = new Concepts();
    co.start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.print(co.code + "==");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to use code formats properly

Comment: To understand why, you must know some basics about `Thread`s and concurrency. It seems you are [expecting `Thread.start()` and `Runnable.run()` to have identical semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579657/whats-the-difference-between-thread-start-and-runnable-run).

Comment: You need a tutorial on threads and concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing a second thread that sets the `code` instance variable to `7` without any synchronization.

And you access the `code` variable from your main thread, again without any synchronization.

This means that the main thread may see the state of the `code` variable prior to the other thread setting it to `7` (which means it would print `9` until it observes the change made by the other thread), or it may not (which means it would only print `7`s). It all depends on which thread will run first.

Without synchronization you have no reason to expect one outcome over the other.